# Excel Question: How do I make a dynamic drop down when the list is the column name and I want it to show all the row under that column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

Cell `A1` is  drop down with the list of all the columns `G1:K1`
Cell `G2:K6` is the array
Cell `G2:K6` also a drop down with options of Pass and Fail

***Check this for the sample image:***
[image]

***Check this for the another sample image:***
[image]

but once the Cell `A1` is changed all the rows change as well and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `INDEX/Match` combination. Try-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($G$2:$K$6,ROW(1:1),MATCH($A$1,$G$1:$K$1)),"")
```

[image]